# How to read HTTP header from IPv6 socket in C?

Tags: c, http, ipv6, netfilter

I have to read IPv6 scoket, get TCP/UDP and read HTTP header to get URL sent from the host. I used Netfilter kernel APIs to read packet but data is wrongly printed. How to get proper http data/URL sent as a request in C ?

This is code segement I tried.

```
static int sc_get_http_info(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    struct ipv6hdr *ip6h = ipv6_hdr(skb);
    struct tcphdr *tcph = (void *)ip6h + sizeof(struct ipv6hdr);
    unsigned char *data = (void *)tcph  + tcph->doff * 4;
    unsigned int  datalen = (skb)->len - sizeof(struct ipv6hdr) - (tcph->doff * 4);
    printk ("data is %s ", data);
}
```

I assumed the data string pointer should return http data so that I can use URL in HTTP packet in the further code but it returns [image]

This is the ouput I get when it hits the kernel. Sometimes, I get data is 0 as output. I know there can be extension headers in IPv6 packets. If such headers are there, how to traverse all these extension headers and point to HTTP header.

For IPv4, I followed this code and it worked.

```
     static int sc_get_https_info(struct sk_buff *skb)
    {
        struct iphdr *  iph = ip_hdr(skb);
        struct tcphdr * tcph = (void *)iph + iph->ihl * 4;
        unsigned char * data = (void *)tcph + tcph->doff * 4;
        unsigned int    dlen = (skb)->len - (iph->ihl * 4) - (tcph->doff * 4);
}
```

Any help would be useful and appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you cast to `(void *)`?

Comment: Did you try to look up content of a packet in Wireshark etc. and check with your offsets?

Comment: Yes. that seemed confusing. For each packet, the length was different. I checked in dmesg kernel logs. I thought I would traverse the whole packet by using  sizeof operator to structure irrespective of what the IPv6 header contains but that doesn't work. Since, TCP is same for IPv6 and IPv4, I feel it should work.

Comment: AFAIR you can have optional header fields for IPv6 resulting in variable total length of your IP header. And still: why (void*)?

Comment: With IPv6, you need to walk the Next Header fields until you reach the transport protocol, e.g. TCP, header. Once you find the transport datagram, you can deal with it the same way you do for IPv4 because it is independent from the network protocol.